# Where is the scope variable declared in this source code?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've been looking through the source code for devise, for the life of me can't figure out how the below code block works [(full source here)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/base.rb)

```
def mapping
    @mapping ||= begin
        mapping = Devise.mappings[scope]
        raise "Could not find mapping for #{scope}" unless mapping
        mapping
    end
end
```

I think understand most parts of this code, but cannot find where the scope variable is declared/defined. I have searched to repository (and the repository this inherits from), and looked at the tests available to try and get a better idea of what's going on here, but can not find any mention of a `scope` variable anywhere. I'm still learning ruby, so am I missing something obvious/a language construct that I'm unaware of at work here?

Comment: There's only one line of code before it where it could have been defined. It is easy to verify that it isn't defined there, so it cannot possibly be a variable, it must be a method call.

Comment: @JörgWMittag if you look at the source code linked, the class this method belongs to extends the class Warden::Strategies::Base, in which it declares and defines the value inside the initialize method - I simply didn't search the Warden repo source thoroughly enough to see this definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `warden` stuff. Check this out

https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/strategies/base.rb

this line

```
class Base < ::Warden::Strategies::Base
```

should have given you an hint :)